# Retaining gridview sorting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview on that i am having 5-6 columns, I have done sorting true on gridview and it is sortable through every column by cliking on the header of every column. Now what i want is , I want to retain sorting criteria , when user comes again on my website, he will find that the grid is sorted with the column which he had previously selected.
Please help me out implementing this using Cookies.

Comment: Please help me out as i need it right here. Thanks a lot :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to handle the [Sorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting) event, which is raised server-side by the runtime when the user has triggered a postback by clicking one of the gridview column header links. Your handler will be given a GridViewSortEventArgs object containing the expression being sorted by and the direction being sorted. Simply combine these in some reversible way into a string, then add the data as a Cookie for your site:

```
Response.Cookies["myPageCookie"]["SortCriteria"] = e.SortExpression + "|" + e.SortDirection;
```

... and in the Load handler for the page, if the load is not for a postback (meaning it's a "first-time" load), try to get the cookie for the page's sort criteria from the Request.Cookies collection, and if it exists, after loading the data, call GridView.Sort() passing in this data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store this criteria in some persistent media ether a disk file or DataBase dependent what is more fits your case.

Comment: The OP's request is perfectly doable using cookies. The data isn't security-related, it's simply remembering a display preference. There's no need to store every sort preference of every unique visitor to the site since the dawn of time in a database.

Comment: You are correct but cookies are bound to every request going to the server so by moving data to the cookie you increasing volume of data reaching the server and slowing down slightly all user requests

Comment: And you'd need to query the DB for the user's preference, slowing down server-side response. We're talking about a *maximum* of 4KB per cookie; the average site is slowed down more by ViewState hogging.

Comment: You can cache it , 4KB per request is allot for front facing popular sites

Comment: Cache it where? If it's in ViewState it bloats page size, and most RESTful programmers I know hate using Session for anything that doesn't absolutely have to be known to the server for the entire session.

Comment: In Application or Cache objects

Comment: Michael, I need to store it in cookies... and if user visits my page after setting some sorting criteria on grid, i want him to enjoy the same sorted set if data which he had when he last visited the page...

Comment: Yeah Keith u r right, my data is not something related to security, and cookies is the best way to do it, thanks for your suggestion :)